# Write lines of text to a file in R

Tags: file-io, r

In the R scripting language, how do I write lines of text, e.g., the following two lines

```
Hello
World
```

to a file named "output.txt"?

Answer (score 547, accepted):

```
fileConn<-file("output.txt")
writeLines(c("Hello","World"), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Comment: Mark - what If I have several threads all of which I would like to add lines to the same file? (The issue being is that you can't have more then one connection to a file, If I am not mistaken)

Thanks.

Comment: @Tal, that is an excellent question, you should post it as a new, separate question so it'll get some attention.  There are much more knowledgeable R programmers around here than me!

Comment: Note that this requires the file "output.txt" to already exist. If it doesn't, it must be created first, e.g. using 'file.create("output.txt")'.

Comment: @jhin I am not sure if that is true.  Using RStudio 0.98 and R version 3.1.0 the file is created automatically if it doesn't exist

Comment: @JHowIX I just tried reproducing my issue and I can't. Not sure what my problem was at the time, but now everything seems to work as you say. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: The option of `writeLines()` is roughly ten times faster then the combination of `sink()` and `cat()`

Comment: You need not open and close the file because writeLines() will do that for you.  See @petermeissner's answer.

Comment: @Mark `> coefficients<-file("coefficients")
> writeLines(summary(model),coefficients)
Error in writeLines(summary(model), coefficients) : 
  invalid 'text' argument`

Comment: `close` will return an error because **`writeLines` already closes the connection**. From `?writeLines`: "If the connection is open it is written from its current position. If it is not open, it is opened for the duration of the call in "wt" mode and then closed again."

Comment: @user57423, actually no.  The full docs say `If the con is a character string, the function calls file to obtain a file connection which is opened
for the duration of the function call.
If the connection is open it is written from its current position. If it is not open, it is opened for the
duration of the call in "wt" mode and then closed again.`  Which means if the `con` argument is a string, R assumes it to be a file path and opens a connection.  If R opens the connection, it closes it.  In my code snippet, I'm passing in a connection and R will not auto-close it.

Comment: @Mark You are right. I missed the `file()`. The same code without `file()` – i.e. `fileConn<-"output.txt"` – writes the same file, but returns `Error in UseMethod("close") : no applicable method for 'close' applied to an object of class "character"`.

Comment: `writeLines(c("Hello","World"), "output.txt")` does the opening and closing automatically like in the given answer.

Comment: @TalGalili did you ask that excellent question of yours in comments (multithread read / write to the same file) anywhere in SO ? Can you please post a link to that, it would add to this thread's value. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to see the mutithread one too

Answer (score 189):

Actually you **can** do it with `sink()`:

```
sink("outfile.txt")
cat("hello")
cat("\n")
cat("world")
sink()
```

hence do:

```
file.show("outfile.txt")
# hello
# world
```

Comment: sink() doesn't work on Databricks be careful. 
You can use put all these inside a function and call this function like

capture.output(funciton call, filename)

Comment: Thanks for this @aL3xa. But keep in mind that this code effectively writes everything from the console, including the code exectured.

Answer (score 151):

I would use the `cat()` command as in this example:

```
> cat("Hello",file="outfile.txt",sep="\n")
> cat("World",file="outfile.txt",append=TRUE)
```

You can then view the results from with R with

```
> file.show("outfile.txt")
hello
world
```

Comment: It constantly opens & closes a file. This approach might be inefficient.

Answer (score 90):

What's about a simple `writeLines()`?

```
txt <- "Hallo\nWorld"
writeLines(txt, "outfile.txt")
```

or

```
txt <- c("Hallo", "World")
writeLines(txt, "outfile.txt")
```

Comment: nice to show that the input doesn't have to be a vector of lines

Comment: @tim Actually `"Hallo\nWorld"` is a length one vector of the character type. Just try `txt <- "Hallo\nWorld"; is.character(txt) && length(txt) == 1 && is.vector(txt)`

Comment: This works for me only as `writeLines(txt, con="outfile.txt")`.

Comment: nope, should work without naming arguments as long as you give a valid file name as second argument.

Comment: @petermeissner `> coefficients<-summary(model)
> writeLines(coefficients, "coefficients")
Error in writeLines(coefficients, "coefficients") : 
  invalid 'text' argument`

Comment: You cannot simply write anything to a file (*"invalid 'text' argument"*). It has to be character vector: e.g.:``library(magrittr);
data.frame(y=1:10, x=rnorm(10)) %>% 
lm() %>% 
summary() %>% 
capture.output() %>% 
writeLines("coef.txt");
readLines("coef.txt")``

Answer (score 26):

I suggest:

```
writeLines(c("Hello","World"), "output.txt")
```

It is shorter and more direct than the current accepted answer.
It is not necessary to do:

```
fileConn<-file("output.txt")
# writeLines command using fileConn connection
close(fileConn)
```

Because the documentation for `writeLines()` says:

> If the `con` is a character string, the function calls `file` to obtain
>   a file connection which is opened for the duration of the function
>   call.

```
# default settings for writeLines(): sep = "\n", useBytes = FALSE
# so: sep = "" would join all together e.g.
```

Comment: It's good to add that writeLines can print only character vectors.

Answer (score 24):

You could do that in a single statement

```
cat("hello","world",file="output.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 21):

Short ways to *write lines of text to a file in R* could be realised with [cat](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/cat) or [writeLines](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/writeLines) as already shown in many answers. Some of the shortest possibilities might be:

```
cat("Hello\nWorld", file="output.txt")
writeLines("Hello\nWorld", "output.txt")
```

In case you don't like the "\n" you could also use the following style:

```
cat("Hello
World", file="output.txt")

writeLines("Hello
World", "output.txt")
```

While `writeLines` adds a *newline* at the end of the file what is not the case for `cat`.
This behaviour could be adjusted by:

```
writeLines("Hello\nWorld", "output.txt", sep="") #No newline at end of file
cat("Hello\nWorld\n", file="output.txt") #Newline at end of file
cat("Hello\nWorld", file="output.txt", sep="\n") #Newline at end of file
```

But main difference is that `cat` uses *R objects* and `writeLines` a *character vector* as argument. So writing out e.g. the numbers *1:10* needs to be casted for writeLines while it can be used as it is in cat:

```
cat(1:10)
writeLines(as.character(1:10))
```

and `cat` can take *many* objects but `writeLines` only *one* vector:

```
cat("Hello", "World", sep="\n")
writeLines(c("Hello", "World"))
```

Append to an existing file is easier with `cat`. But this option will permanently open and close the file for each transaction. So for many appending writings a connection might be preferable. The `a` in the command `file` stands for *Open for appending in text mode*. Another option will be `w` for *Open for writing in text mode* to create a new file for writing.

```
cat("Hello\n", file="output.txt")
cat("World", file="output.txt", append=TRUE)

cat("Hello\n", file="output.txt")
CON <- file("output.txt", "a")
cat("World", file=CON)
close(CON)

writeLines("Hello", "output.txt")
CON <- file("output.txt", "a")
writeLines("World", CON)
close(CON)
```

On the other hand `writeLines` is faster than `cat`.

```
bench::mark(check=FALSE,
writeLines(c("Hello", "World")),
cat("Hello", "World", sep="\n"),
writeLines(c("Hello", "World"), sep=" "),
cat(c("Hello", "World")),
cat("Hello", "World") )
#  expression                                      min   median `itr/sec` mem_a…¹
#  <bch:expr>                                 <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:b>
#1 writeLines(c("Hello", "World"))              2.27µs   4.77µs   163878.      0B
#2 cat("Hello", "World", sep = "\n")            3.83µs   8.51µs   118708.      0B
#3 writeLines(c("Hello", "World"), sep = " ")   1.99µs   4.25µs   235944.      0B
#4 cat(c("Hello", "World"))                      4.1µs   6.84µs   141797.      0B
#5 cat("Hello", "World")                        3.46µs   7.06µs   129865.      0B
```

Answer (score 12):

tidyverse edition with pipe and `write_lines()` from readr

```
library(tidyverse)
c('Hello', 'World') %>% write_lines( "output.txt")
```

Answer (score 5):

What about a simple `write.table()`?

```
text = c("Hello", "World")
write.table(text, file = "output.txt", col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = F)
```

The parameters `col.names = FALSE` and `row.names = FALSE` make sure to exclude the row and column names in the txt, and the parameter `quote = FALSE` excludes those quotation marks at the beginning and end of each line in the txt.
To read the data back in, you can use `text = readLines("output.txt")`.

Answer (score 2):

### The ugly system option

```
ptf <- function (txtToPrint,outFile){system(paste(paste(paste("echo '",cat(txtToPrint),sep = "",collapse = NULL),"'>",sep = "",collapse = NULL),outFile))}
#Prints txtToPrint to outFile in cwd. #!/bin/bash echo txtToPrint > outFile
```

Answer (score 2):

To round out the possibilities, you can use `writeLines()` with `sink()`, if you want:

```
> sink("tempsink", type="output")
> writeLines("Hello\nWorld")
> sink()
> file.show("tempsink", delete.file=TRUE)
Hello
World
```

To me, it always seems most intuitive to use `print()`, but if you do that the output won't be what you want:

```
...
> print("Hello\nWorld")
...
[1] "Hello\nWorld"
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2470277):

```
file <- file("test.txt")
writeLines(yourObject, file)
close(file)
```

Note that the `yourObject` needs to be in a string format; use `as.character()` to convert if you need.

But this is too much typing for **every** save attempt. Let's create a snippet in RStudio.

In Global Options >> Code >> Snippet, type this:

```
snippet wfile
    file <- file(${1:filename})
    writeLines(${2:yourObject}, file)
    close(file)
```

Then, during coding, **type `wfile` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>**.

Comment: The `file <- file(...)` line looks suspicious to me. Isn't it both invoking `file` as a function and assigning `file` a new meaning? Does `file()` work even after this piece of code runs? Don't have access to an R installation to test myself right now...

Comment: it worked on my setup @Palec
You can change file to youFile if you have some problem with reserved words

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of R, `writeLines` will preserve returns and spaces in your text, so you don't need to include `\n` at the end of lines and you can write one big chunk of text to a file. This will work with the example,

```
txt <- "Hello
World"
fileConn<-file("output.txt")
writeLines(txt, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

But you could also use this setup to simply include text with structure (linebreaks or indents)

```
txt <- "Hello
   world
 I can 
   indent text!"
fileConn<-file("output.txt")
writeLines(txt, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```