# Append lines to a file

Tags: r, file, large-data

I'm new using R. I'm trying to add (append) new lines to a file with my existing data in R. The problem is that my data has about 30000 rows and 13000 cols. I already try to add a line with the `writeLines` function but the resulting file contains only the line added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write lines of text to a file in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470248/write-lines-of-text-to-a-file-in-r)

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge Are you sure this is a dupe? The Q [Write lines of text to a file in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2470248/3817004) you have linked to is about writing lines to a file in general while this Q asks specifically about _appending_ lines to an existing file.

Comment: @UweBlock True, but the linked Q discusses the append option in many of its answers.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge It's just 2 of the 8 answers in the linked Q. Both suggest `cat()`. Both are rather terse. None of them explains why they use the `append` option or the effect this option has. No other answer (`writeLines()`, `sink()`) mention or discuss the `append` option.

Comment: @UweBlock Ok, sure, I'll retract

Answer (score 132):

Have you tried using the [`write`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/write.html) function?

```
line="blah text blah blah etc etc"
write(line,file="myfile.txt",append=TRUE)
```

Comment: make sure you don't use a connection as file, but just put in the file path, otherwise append won't work!

Comment: @Ansjovis86 could you pls elaborate a bit more on "connection as file"?

Comment: @munmunbb This is only when you use a connect setup. If you don't have it don't worry about. If you have it, drop it from your code and this answer will work.

Comment: While this may be very obvious to many, I had alway previously read the existing file, used rbind to add a line to it and then written the updated file again. I now see that this is grossly inefficient and that using write to append a line is far faster.

Comment: `write` is not really meant to write a simple string to a file. [Use `cat` for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7741730/1048186).  As [the documentation for the write command](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/write) states, "The data (usually a matrix) `x` are written to file `file`."

Comment: I've had issues with `write` doing very odd things with my data -- I'm guessing because it is somehow interpreting it.

Answer (score 42):

`write.table`, `write.csv` and others all have the `append=` argument, which appends `append=TRUE` and usually overwrites if `append=FALSE`. So which one you want to / have to use, depends on your data.

By the way, `cat()` can also be used to write text to a file and also has the `append=` argument.

Comment: Or even `sink(append = TRUE)`.

Comment: For plain text data, use `cat()` instead of `write()`.  As [the documentation for the write command](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/write) states, "The data (usually a matrix) `x` are written to file `file`." `write()` is not meant for simple string data. It's meant to format more complex types and it wraps around `cat()` to do the actual writing to the file. When using `cat()`, you will need to `paste0(line,"\n")`  to put a newline on the end of the file.

Answer (score 6):

You can open a connection in append mode to *append lines to an existing file with `writeLines`*.

```
writeLines("Hello", "output.txt") #Create file
CON <- file("output.txt", "a")    #Open connection to append
writeLines("World", CON)          #Append: World
writeLines("End", CON)            #Append: End
close(CON)                        #Close connection
```

Basically the same but using `cat`, with the difference that the file is opened and closed on every operation, what can reduce performance.

```
cat("Hello\n", file = "output.txt")
cat("World\n", file = "output.txt", append = TRUE)
cat("End", file = "output.txt", append = TRUE)
```

Using `cat` with a connection, like above with `writeLines`.

```
cat("Hello\n", file = "output.txt")
CON <- file("output.txt", "a")
cat("World\n", file = CON)
cat("End", file = CON)
close(CON)
```

In case of creating a file and appending subsequent.

```
CON <- file("output.txt", "w")
writeLines("Hello", CON)
writeLines("World", CON)
writeLines("End", CON)
close(CON)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(listOfVector, function(anyNameofVect){ write(anyNameofVect, file="outputFileName", sep="\t", append=TRUE, ncolumns=100000) })
```

or

```
lapply(listOfVector, write, file="outputFileName", sep="\t", append=TRUE, ncolumns=100000)
```

Comment: overly complicated when considering the 'write' command will append.