# Text under generated table in .csv file in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv, footnotes

For weekly reports I generate, I create a .csv file for my outputs which has 9 columns and 7 rows.

I use this command to create my file:

```
write.csv(table, paste('home/weekly_',start.date,'.csv',sep=''), row.names=F)
```

Note: 'table' is a matrix (I believe that's the right R terminology)

I would like to add a footnote/note under the table in this file, would this be possible?

For example, if I were to create a text file instead of a .csv file, I would use the following commands:

```
cat("Number of participants not eligible:")
cat(length(which((tbl[,'Reg_age_dob']<=18) & as.Date(tbl[,'DateWithdrew'])>='2013-01-01'& as.Date(tbl[,'DateWithdrew'])<'2013-04-01' & as.Date(tbl[,'QuestionnaireEndDate'])<'2013-01-01' )))
cat("\n")
```

How would I do this to appear under the table in a .csv output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing the CSV part, just append the rest as new lines using

```
write("Footer",file="myfile",append=TRUE)
```

Solution from here: [Add lines to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741575/add-lines-to-a-file)

But be aware of the fact, that a CSV parser will be a upset, if you do not use comment tags correctly.

It might be better to use a second file for your purpose.

Comment: Does this work when the content I want to  include under the table needs to be generated? i.e length(which((tbl[,'Reg_age_dob']<=18) & as.Date(tbl[,'DateWithdrew'])>='2013-01-01'& as.Date(tbl[,'DateWithdrew'])<'2013-04-01' & as.Date(tbl[,'QuestionnaireEndDate'])<'2013-01-01' )))

Comment: Just replace "Footer" by whatever you need (and data you have available.).