# Appending text in write function [R]

Tags: r, append, overwrite

I am trying to append a line in an already existing `.txt` file. But my syntax overwrites this file :(

```
   fileConn <- file( "realization1.txt" )
      write(x =as.character(max(cumsum( rnorm( 10^7)))),
            file = fileConn,
            append = TRUE, sep = " ")


      write(x =as.character(max(cumsum( rnorm( 10^7)))),
            file = fileConn,
            append = TRUE, sep = " ")
   }

   close( fileConn )
```

Does anybody have any solution to this?
Thanks for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add lines to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741575/add-lines-to-a-file)

Comment: not ture. The answers here are different. Check @carl solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your difficulty comes from failing to open the file with the proper attributes set.

If you create the connection with  `fileConn <- file( "realization1.txt" ,open="a")` , then all will work as you expect.  Basically, so far as I can tell,  `write` (which is a wrapper for `cat` )  cannot append unless the file connection was opened with "append" allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `writeLines`, which is about 20x faster than `write`. This makes a big difference if you are appending large character strings.

```
sink("outfile.txt", append = T)

x <- as.character(max(cumsum( rnorm( 10^7))))
writeLines(x)

sink()
```

Comment: And what about writeLines and write.table comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the command *write.table*

```
write.table(max(cumsum( rnorm( 10^7))),file="realization1.txt",append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)

write.table(max(cumsum( rnorm( 10^7))),file="realization1.txt",append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

You will find the 2 values in the 'realizaion1.txt' file