# How to add lines to a textfile using connection as file

Tags: r, text-files

In this post it is explained how to write lines to a textfile:

[Add lines to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741575/add-lines-to-a-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Although it is not possible to use connection as file.
For that reason it is not possible to run this code:

```
for (i in 1:10)
```

{

```
    con <- file("en_US.twitter.txt", "r")
    line <- readLines(con, i)  
    write(line,file="D:/myfile.txt",append=TRUE)

next
```

}

Is there a way to overcome this?

Thank you!

Comment: do you want the `con <- ...` line to be *outside* of the loop?

Comment: @lefft  thank you, i will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want to concatenate two files?

```
txt1 <- "Lorem ipsum dolor amet polaroid hot chicken pork belly, mlkshk commodo \
typewriter excepteur. Meditation mixtape edison bulb ad venmo duis mollit \
veniam poke voluptate celiac everyday carry vape hot chicken ea."

txt2 <- "Incididunt copper mug direct trade hella taxidermy. Occupy chia in \
laborum subway tile cornhole XOXO echo park green juice try-hard sustainable. \
Put a bird on it bicycle rights hell of non chillwave blog slow-carb shoreditch \
organic ad waistcoat stumptown qui.\n"

write(txt1, "1.txt")
write(txt2, "2.txt")

# append 1.txt to 2.txt
li <- readLines("1.txt")
write(li, "2.txt", append=TRUE)

cat(readLines("2.txt"), sep="\n")
```

If you just want to append the first n (in this case 2) lines

```
write(txt1, "1.txt")
write(txt2, "2.txt")

li <- readLines("1.txt", 2)
write(li, "2.txt", append=TRUE)

cat(readLines("2.txt"), sep="\n")
```

To append only specific line numbers (in this case 1 and 3)

```
write(txt1, "1.txt")
write(txt2, "2.txt")

li <- readLines("1.txt")
write(li[c(1, 3)], "2.txt", append=TRUE)

cat(readLines("2.txt"), sep="\n")
```

Comment: My endgoal is to copy specific linenumbers from the file twitter.txt to myfile.txt. This in order to make a subsample from twitter.txt.

Comment: The output from `readLines()` is just a character vector. You can select the elements as you would with any other vector.

Comment: What kind of other vector for example?

Comment: See [here](https://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html) for an introduction to R data types, and [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: thanks, i will try to integrate your answer in my code. Although i think the problem is in using connection as file. (See also the original post)

Comment: @user2165379: Is it absolutely necessary to use `connection()`?

Comment: I have tried to put the connection outside of the loop and close it, although this gives a long error. setwd("D:/coursera/Capstone/Coursera-SwiftKey/final/en_US")
con <- file("en_US.twitter.txt", "r")
allelines <- readLines(con)
close(con)

for (i in 1:10) 
  {print(i)

        myline <- readLines(allelines, i)  
        write(myline,file="D:/coursera/Capstone/Coursera-SwiftKey/final/en_US/myfile.txt",append=TRUE)
        
    next
  }

Comment: What I mean is that this whole `con <- file("en_US.twitter.txt", "r"); allelines <- readLines(con); close(con)` dance seems unnecessary. You can use `readLines()` and `write()` without all that. Like I did in my answer above. Just change `"1.txt"` etc. to the path of your files.

Comment: that would be great. I will try tomorrow and let you know! Thanks for your help!

Comment: That is the solution!  I runs fine now without (con) as you mentioned.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2165379: Good to hear