# Execute a file in the working directory and paste the results in a text file

Tags: r

I have a sample application where it creates a dummy text file in the working directory. Now I have another R file(add.R) where I need to execute it and paste the results in a text file. Below is the reprex

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
source("add.R")


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  textInput("name", "Name: "),
  textOutput("greeting"),
  actionButton("checkme","checkme"),
  selectInput("Slider","Slider",choices = unique(iris$Species))
  )
  )
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
source("add.R")


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  myfileexists <- eventReactive(input$checkme,{
    file.exists("test2.txt")  
    })
  output$greeting <- renderText({
    paste0("Hello, ", input$name, "Does your file exist ?", myfileexists())
  })
  print(getwd())
  file.create("test2.txt")
  })
```

add.R

```
a <- 3 + 4
b <- 3 + t
```

Expected out put. IN case any error, the application should show error occurred

text2.txt file

> a <- 3 + 4
>
> a
>
> [1] 7
>
> b <- 3 + t
>
> Error in 3 + t : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: That's a side-effect of choosing a single-letter variable name in a not-very-reproducible environment, when the variable name also happens to be a base R function, for `t`ranspose. If `t` were not defined and not a function, I would expect `Error: object 't' not found`, but instead you got that error. Try with another *function*, as in `3+paste`, and you'll get your error. Overall, this tells me either you have a typo; you are not managing your variable scope; or you are expecting non-literal programming (symbolic/non-standard stuff?).

Comment: I agree with you. Overall my question was different :) It is actually is there a way to Execute a file in the working directory and paste the results in a text file

Comment: Define "execute file". You can always write to text file [by appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741575/add-lines-to-a-file).

Comment: Do you mean `source` the file?