# writing data to a file in R

Tags: r, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write lines of text to a file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470248/write-lines-of-text-to-a-file-in-r)

Is there anyway to write information to a file in R like other languages such as Python or Java?
I mean first open a file to be written and then write the contents of what I do line by line. Actually I do not want to put all my data in a matrix or list first.
Thanks

Comment: please work on your *accept-rate.*

Comment: "write the contents of what I do line by line" sounds like savehistory(). If that isn't what you mean, please be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `?connections`.

For example, from the help for `?file`:

```
 zz <- file("ex.data", "w")  # open an output file connection
 cat("TITLE extra line", "2 3 5 7", "", "11 13 17", file = zz, sep = "\n")
 cat("One more line\n", file = zz)
 close(zz)
 readLines("ex.data")
```

[1] "TITLE extra line" "2 3 5 7"          ""                 "11 13 17"
[5] "One more line"

Clean up:

```
 unlink("ex.data")
```

See `?cat`, `?writeLines`, `?writeBin`, and several others in the See Also section of the `?connections` help page.

You can also append with `write.table`, either with its `append` argument or by writing to an open connection.

Comment: +1 - This is the preferred approach as it uses a single file connection.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `?write`. You can write line by line using `append=TRUE`. Also `?sink` might be of interest to you.