# cannot open the connection in Shiny

Tags: r, file, shiny

All,
I am trying to write a data frame into RDS file in Shiny app. I am using below code.

```
AgName <- gsub("\\s","",paste(mtrl1,'_',stage1,'_',sample1,'.RDS', collapse = ' '))
saveRDS(Input_Data2, AgName )
```

But it is throwing following error message:

```
Error: cannot open the connection
```

Same code is running fine on R command line but not in Shiny app. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

---

Thanks Flick!

I used below code as well, but no luck.

```
setwd("/opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps/P-AG-Disc4/")
AgName <- gsub("\\s","",paste(mtrl1,'_',stage1,'_',sample1,'.csv', collapse = ' '))
saveRDS(Input_Data2, file=AgName )
```

---

Thanks Flick!

You were right. Directory was not having write permission on the directy, where I was trying to write. Thanks again soo much!

Comment: It's likely R and Shiny might have different working directories when they run by default. Try looking at the results from `getwd()` from each and make sure Shiny is writing to the place you think it is and has permissions to do so. Or at least show us the value of `AgName`

Comment: Can you verify the value of `AgName` is correct?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same issue. I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470248/write-lines-of-text-to-a-file-in-r) and used the below given code to resolve this. I used this code, and it ran fine:

```
  wrtfun2<-reactive({
  if (!is.null(input$var1))
  setwd("/opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps/test")
  sink("outfile.txt")
  cat(input$var1)
  sink()
  }
)
```

I also changed the permission on the directory where I was trying to write and It worked finally.

Comment: Thanks. This just saved me a bunch of time as a Shiny newbie.