# Error : ShinyApp cannot open the connection

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I tried to publish a shinyapp to both shinyapp.io and rstudioconnect.com but there has connection error, here I raised [Unable publish to RStudio Connect : Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : Reader error: control characters are not allowed: #81 at 276 #115](https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/115) and [Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : Reader error: control characters are not allowed: #81 at 276 #31](https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/issues/31). It works locally but once publish became error as you can see whole knitting process via below gif.

I've recorded few animated gif to know the error thoroughly. [error 01](https://i.imgur.com/Oyx9yoE.gifv), [error 02](https://i.imgur.com/2FsHVYl.gifv), [error 03](https://i.imgur.com/1LWPHws.gifv). Kindly refer to the gif, here I also refer to some articles who faced similar error.

- [Shiny app turns grey when deployed, works fine locally](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/issues/190)
- [(shinyapps.io) ERROR: cannot open the connection](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/47d7vu/shinyappsio_error_cannot_open_the_connection/?st=isy48ra8&sh=d821cb40)
- [ERROR: cannot open the connection](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/Yr8q5ZmM5e0)
- [cannot open the connection in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039515/cannot-open-the-connection-in-shiny)
- [ERROR: cannot open the connection in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604351/error-cannot-open-the-connection-in-r-shiny#_=_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its work, but take few minutes to open the webpage... [test shinyapp](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/1766/)

I forgot to attach the data and functions into the shinyapp, I wondered some functions unable found while I just simply add `googleVis::` and `purrr::` to get the require function from load the package.

Comment: finally solved it, regressionApps at https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/1807/, and the source codes https://github.com/scibrokes/betting-strategy-and-model-validation