# How to open these features in r?

Tags: r

**I'm not able to open these resources in r.**

```
source("http://www.zzlab.net/GAPIT/emma.txt")
source("http://www.zzlab.net/GAPIT/gapit_functions.txt")
source("http://www.zzlab.net/FarmCPU/FarmCPU_functions.txt")
```

**The following error appears:**

> Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the
> connection
> In addition: Warning message: In file(filename, "r",
> encoding = encoding) : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The hostname of this
> certificate does not is valid or does not match'

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work on my machine

```r
r_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".R")
r_con  <- file(r_path)
writeLines(text = readLines("http://www.zzlab.net/GAPIT/emma.txt"), con = r_con) # taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2470277/6105259
close(r_con)
source(r_path)
```