# comparison of methods for saving text from R: writeLines(), cat(), and sink()

Tags: r

This question, [Write lines of text to a file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470248/write-lines-of-text-to-a-file-in-r), shows three different for saving outputs to a plain text file. Using the example from the question, let's say that we want to create a file named `output.txt` with this text:

```
Hello
World
```

The question's answers show three methods:

1. Using `writeLines()`:

```r
fileConn<-file("output.txt")
writeLines(c("Hello","World"), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

2. Using `sink()`:

```r
sink("outfile.txt")
cat("hello")
cat("\n")
cat("world")
sink()
```

3. Using `cat()`:

```r
cat("Hello",file="outfile.txt",sep="\n")
cat("World",file="outfile.txt",append=TRUE)
```

Some of the answers and comments note that `cat()` would be slower than the other two methods.
However, my questions are:

1. Are there situations when one method is better than the others?
2. If one method is more idiomatically correct or quicker than the other two methods in R, why?

I searched SO and only found the linked answer.
I have found other *why* question on SO (e.g., [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array)) so I think this question is on topic for the site.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but think it could go off in many tangents. Do you have any more info about your intended use-case or some direction for answering the questions? For instance, `sink()` is inherently different in my opinion, because it diverts output from the console. `writeLines()` seems like the best option for dealing with a lot of text... and so on.

Comment: Not an answer, but `capture.output(cat("Hello\nWorld\n"), file="outfile.txt")` is a fourth option.

Comment: @Matt `because it diverts output from the console` is part of an answer I'm looking for. I could not find any broad R documentation about why to use one function over another.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cat), `cat()` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, converts them to character vectors, concatenates them and appends the given separator to each element. `writeLines()` accepts a single character vector and writes it to a connection. 

The docs suggest that `cat()` is useful for producing output in user-defined functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short performance comparison give clear advantage to `writeLines`:

```r
system.time(writeLines(con = 'writeLines.txt',text = paste('Line ',1:100000)))
#>        user      system       total 
#>        0.17        0.01        0.18

system.time(cat( paste('Line ',1:100000),file="cat.txt",sep="\n"))
#>        user      system       total 
#>        0.25        0.85        1.11
```

Looking at C code, `cat` uses `RPrintf` located in [builtin.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/builtin.c).

> All printing in R is done via the functions Rprintf and REprintf
> or their (v) versions Rvprintf and REvprintf.
> These routines work exactly like (v)printf(3).  Rprintf writes to
> ``standard output''.
> It is redirected by the sink() function

As stated above, using `sink()` allows to redirect the connection. Redirecting once to a file using `sink()` is definitely faster than opening a new connection / appending data / closing for each new line as with `cat(file=..., append=TRUE)`.

`writeLines` uses a dedicated C function `Rconn_printf` located in [connections.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/connections.c) and is quicker.

To sum up :

- `cat` is the standard R output to console
- `sink` allows to redirect `cat` output to another connection, for example a file, allowing to write multiple lines without reopening the connection
- `writeLines` is quicker than `sink+cat` for file output

Suggestion, when to use which:

- I like `cat()` to log R script progress in console mode. Once the script is validated, `sink()` allows to redirect this output to a file if needed and might be useful for script automation.
- I use `writeLines()` when I specifically want to write data (not just log) to a file because of it's better performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is either route more idiomatic for R for simple applications? Also, thanks for explaining the why.

Comment: I like `cat` to log R script progress in console mode. Once the script is validated, `sink` allows to redirect this to a file if needed : might be useful for script automation. I use `writeLines` when I specifically want to write data (not just log) to a file because of it's better performance.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance about when to use which. I guess that's what I was originally looking for, even if my question was not clear. I edited your guidance into the question. Please edit if needed. Also, I gave you the bounty because of your guidance.

Comment: @RichardErickson The output of **both**, `cat` and `writeLines` go per default to the console and for **both** their output can be redirected to a file using `sink`. So in this point there is no difference. The difference is, that `cat` can take *R objects* which need to be converted to character, what needs time and so `cat` is slower than `writeLines` as `writeLines` takes only a *character vector* which can be send out as it is.

Answer (score 4):

`cat` uses *R objects* and `writeLines` one *character vector*.
`cat` converts numeric/complex elements in the same way as `print`
and not in the way as `as.character`, so `options` `digits` and `scipen` are relevant.

```
options(digits = 3)
x <- 0.123456789

cat("Result:", x)
#Result: 0.123

writeLines(paste("Result:", x))
#Result: 0.123456789

writeLines(paste("Result:", format(x)))
#Result: 0.123

writeLines(c("Result:", format(x)), sep=" ")
#Result: 0.123
```

Using *R objects* and converting them will take time.
In case of having a *character vector* `writeLines` will be as convenient as `cat` but more efficient.
In case having different objects `cat` will be more convenient but slower.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is either route more idiomatic for R for simple applications?

Comment: If there is only a character vector and speed matters use `writeLines`. If there are different types `cat` would be easier from my point of view but will be slower.

Comment: Would mind editing that into the answer? under a # when to use-type header?

Comment: I have thought this is already with other words in the answer with: *In case of having a character vector `writeLines` will be as convenient as `cat` but more efficient.
In case having different objects `cat` will be more convenient but slower.**

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance in R it is almost always worth looking into library([data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)).

Here is a benchmark taking into account `data.table::fwrite`:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  writeLines = {
    writeLines(con = 'writeLines.txt', text = paste('Line', 1:100000))
  },
  cat = {
    cat(paste('Line', 1:100000), file = "cat.txt", sep = "\n")
  },
  fwrite = {
    fwrite(as.list(paste('Line', 1:100000)), file = "fwrite.txt", sep = "\n")
  },
  times = 1L
)
```

---

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 writeLines  202.5904  202.5904  202.5904  202.5904  202.5904  202.5904     1
        cat 1234.6644 1234.6644 1234.6644 1234.6644 1234.6644 1234.6644     1
     fwrite  106.8576  106.8576  106.8576  106.8576  106.8576  106.8576     1
```

Comment: Thank you for the benchmark. Does data.table have a way to write plain text, like "hello world! This is the output from an print(lm) * 1000 " in a non-CSV or tidydata style file?

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting the question correctly but as long as you wrap it in a list it should be working: `fwrite(list("hello world! This is the output from an print(lm) * 1000 "), file = "test.txt", sep = "\n")`

Comment: with sink("text.txt") one can dump outputs to a text file such as `print(lm(...))`. Would that work with `fwrite()` or would the data need to formatted? The fwrite docs says it is for CSV-type data https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/fwrite

Comment: Yes - `fwrite` is intended to write csv files but it can be used to write "lines" as well (or a single column). `fwrite` expects a list of same length vectors as its input - accordingly (afaik) it can't directly work on R output.