# writeLines - only the last line is in text file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to output my analysis from my R code through multiple write-commands as mentioned below. However, I am getting only one last line output to my text file.

Code:

```
# Create a report file
report_file <- file("XYZ.txt")

# Write findings to the report file
writeLines("Report on Weather Analysis\n", report_file)

writeLines("\n3. Correlations between Weather Conditions and Departure Delays\n", report_file)
writeLines(paste("Correlation between Average Wind Speed and Departure Delays:", correlation_wind_speed), report_file)
writeLines(paste("Correlation between Wind Gust and Departure Delays:", correlation_wind_gust), report_file)
writeLines(paste("Correlation between Precipitation and Departure Delays:", correlation_precipitation), report_file)

# Close the report file
close(report_file)
```

I have also added the output provided through above lines of code from the text file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akd5P.png)

I am getting only one last line output to my text file. I need all my writeLines details in the output file. Please advice, if anyone has any expertise in this regards? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write lines of text to a file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470248/write-lines-of-text-to-a-file-in-r)

Comment: Each call to `writeLines` is over-writing the file. You need to use a connection (see the previous comment), combine all strings into one vector, or use `write(..., append=TRUE)`` function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't open the connection, so R will open it and close it on each write operation, overwriting what was there before.  Change the first line to

```
report_file <- file("XYZ.txt", open = "wt")
```

and it should work.  The `"wt"` specification says "write as text".  It would also be fine to say `"w"`, but I find the explicit `t` makes the intention clearer.  Other possibilities are described in the "Modes" section of the help page `?file`.